# How can I select an element which has only a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Here is my selector:

```
doc.on("click", ".add_your_qora", function(e){
```

My code will select this:

```
<div class="add_your_qora"> whatever </div>
```

My code will select this too:

```
<div class="add_your_qora another_class_name"> whatever </div>
```

All I'm trying to do is avoiding it. The second element shouldn't be selected, because it doesn't have **only** `add_your_qora` class. How should I write my selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the current element [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) length is greater than 1:

```js
$(doc).on("click", ".add_your_qora", function(e) {
  if (this.classList.length > 1) return;

  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="doc">
  <button class="add_your_qora">only add_your_qora</button>
  <button class="add_your_qora another_class">has another class as well</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the element you want is the first one with this class you can use `document.querySelector('.add_your_qora')` which will return only the first element found that matches the selector.

If you want to select all the elements that has `add_your_qora` class except those which also have `another_class` you can use `$('.add_your_qora:not(.another_class)')`.

If you want to select all the elements that have **only** `add_your_qora` class use this selector `[class=another_class]`

Answer (score 0):

alternative way,

```js
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.add_your_qora', function(e){
        if ($(this).attr('class').match(/^add_your_qora$/) == null) return;
        
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add_your_qora"> add_your_qora </div>
<div class="add_your_qora another_class_name"> add_your_qora another_class_name </div>
```